How to skip ggsave when create plot failed or empty plot
In the code below, how can I skip
ggsave(paste0(single_color,"_plot.png"))
when the code
plot_data <- diamonds %>% filter(color== single_color) errors or plot_data is empty ?
library(tidyverse)
data("diamonds")
colors_loop <- c(diamonds$color %>% as.character() %>% unique(),"Z")
for (single_color in colors_loop){
   
   plot_data <- diamonds %>% filter(color== single_color)
   
   plot_temp <- plot_data %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x,y))+geom_point()+labs(title=paste0(single_color,"_plot"))

   ggsave(paste0(single_color,"_plot.png"))

}


You could just check if plot_data has any data before even trying to plot it, and skip the plotting code if it doesn't (say if (nrow(plot_data) == 0) { next } to skip to the next colour)

To prevent an error if you supply a non-existent data frame to ggplot, you can use get0. This checks for "existence", returning the object, otherwise NULL. To check for "emptiness" use nrow.
colors_loop <- c(diamonds$color %>% as.character() %>% unique(),"Z")

my_plot <- function(data, cols) {
  data <- get0(substitute(data))
  
  if(is.null(data))
    cat("No data to plot\n")
  else {
    for(single_color in cols) {
      
      plot_data <- data %>% filter(color==single_color)
      
      if(nrow(plot_data)>0) {
        plot_temp <- plot_data %>% 
          ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
          geom_point() +
          labs(title=paste0(single_color,"_plot"))
        
        cat(single_color, ": ")
        ggsave(paste0(single_color, "_plot.png"))
      }
    }
  }
}


my_plot(Diamonds, cols=colors_loop)
#No data to plot

my_plot(diamonds, cols=colors_loop)
#E : Saving 7 x 7 in image
#I : Saving 7 x 7 in image
#J : Saving 7 x 7 in image
#H : Saving 7 x 7 in image
#F : Saving 7 x 7 in image
#G : Saving 7 x 7 in image
#D : Saving 7 x 7 in image

my_plot(diamonds, cols=c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))
#E : Saving 7 x 7 in image
#I : Saving 7 x 7 in image

